# FTP.exe and FTP Web request Directory listing

Tags: ftp, ftpwebrequest

Using FTP.exe I get the files listed when using ls.
But when using FtpWebRequest it turns up empty. I have tried all possible combinations regarding active vs passive and ascii vs binary.

I also have tried all kinds of ftp libraries on the net.

The ftp server is a linux server. The same commands on windows ftp server are no problem by the way.

Comment: I am no .NET developer, but I've danced with FTP a few times.

The most likely explanation is that the format of the directory listing differs from that expected by FtpWebRequest. The various RFCs governing FTP don't cover the output of the LIST or NLIST protocol requests. 

Were I in your shoes I would use Wireshark to record and compare the two conversations: regular command-line FTP vs programmatic use of FtpWebRequest, then check the following: 1) are the creds the same 2) is the directory the same 3) does FtpWebRequest get as far as listing the directory?

Comment: I think you are right. The FtpWebRequest did not get as far as listing the directory. I have found now another library (w. source code) that I have used and worked. See the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a suitable library that mimics ftp.exe. However the parsing of the listing of te Linux FTP server is not exactly how it should be, at least it did list the files for me. 
The library is available with its source code and uses WinInet instead of FTPWebRequest to communicate with the FTP server.

The library is available at: [FTP Lib on Codeplex](https://ftplib.codeplex.com/)